# SQL statement to update specific records, but ignore the record if it contains a certain value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title suggest I need to update the times for days of the week, but ignore records that have a day of the week which is equal to saturday or sunday. The query seems to also update the records that include saturday and sunday which is what I'm trying to avoid.

```
UPDATE openingTimes SET timeOpening = '09:00:00', timeClosing = '18:00:00'
    WHERE departmentId=79
    OR departmentId=3
    OR departmentId=6
    OR departmentId=10
    OR departmentId=15
    OR departmentId=18
    OR departmentId=25
    OR departmentId=29
    OR departmentId=32
    OR departmentId=36
    OR departmentId=40
    OR departmentId=44
    OR departmentId=49
    OR departmentId=54
    OR departmentId=57
    OR departmentId=61
    OR departmentId=67
    OR departmentId=72
    OR departmentId=79
    OR departmentId=83
    OR departmentId=84
    OR departmentId=89
    OR departmentId=95
    OR departmentId=99
    OR departmentId=113
    OR departmentId=118
    OR departmentId=120
    OR departmentId=124
    OR departmentId=131
    OR departmentId=136
    OR departmentId=137
    OR departmentId=142
    OR departmentId=145
    OR departmentId=149
    OR departmentId=157
    OR departmentId=162
    AND NOT (dayOfTheWeek='Saturday' OR dayOfTheWeek='Sunday');
```

Comment: Are those `departmentId`s all that exist or a specific subset of all that exist

Comment: Just a subset of the ones that I require

Comment: So would an `WHERE departmentId IN(79,3,6,......)` do for you

Comment: Yes probably, thanks. I haven't done raw sql queries in a while. I still need to figure out why the and not isnt working though

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Parentheses work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query, this is the right way rather than using multiple or conditions.

```
UPDATE openingTimes SET timeOpening = '09:00:00', timeClosing = '18:00:00'
WHERE departmentId in
(79,3,6,10,15,18,25,29,32,36,40,44,49,54,57,61,67,72,79,83,84,89,95,99,
113,118,120,124,131,136,137,142,145,149,157,162)    
AND dayOfTheWeek NOT in  ('Saturday', 'Sunday');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. How does my original AND NOT behave differently to your NOT IN, or is my syntax completly incorrect for the task I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your original query doesn't work because you need to put parens around the `OR` clauses, e.g. `WHERE (departmentID=79 OR departmentID=3 OR...) AND ...`.

Comment: The Syntax you used     AND NOT (dayOfTheWeek='Saturday' OR dayOfTheWeek='Sunday'); is not correct.  That's not the right way to defile

Comment: @kmoser So the error is in my WHERE clause because I don't initially place it in parens? The AND at the bottom would work otherwise?

Comment: @Rick The `AND` part of the clause is correct by itself. Due to MySQL's rules of operator precedence, you need to put parens around the `OR` clauses to turn them into a single expression, otherwise only the **last** `OR` evaluates as the left side of the `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also

```
UPDATE openingTimes SET timeOpening = case dayOfTheWeek  NOT in  ('Saturday', 
'Sunday') then '09:00:00' else timeOpening  end
,timeClosing  = case dayOfTheWeek  NOT in  ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 
'18:00:00' else timeOpening  end
WHERE departmentId in
(79,3,6,10,15,18,25,29,32,36,40,44,49,54,57,61,67,72,79,83,84,89,95,99,
113,118,120,124,131,136,137,142,145,149,157,162);
```

Comment: Incorrect case statement. Query will not work as expected